# What would cause objectForKey: to return null with a valid string in place?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am having an issue with `NSDictionary` returning `null` for an `NSString` even though the string is in the dictionary. Here is the code:

```
- (void)sourceDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNote {
    NSDictionary *aDict = [aNote userInfo];
    DLog(@"%@", aDict);
    NSString *newSourceString = [aDict objectForKey:@"newSource"];
    DLog(@"%@", newSourceString);
    newSourceString = [newSourceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    DLog(@"%@", newSourceString);
    NSString *inspectorString = [newSourceString stringByAppendingString:@"InspectorController"];
    DLog(@"%@", inspectorString);
    newSourceString = [newSourceString stringByAppendingString:@"ViewController"];
    DLog(@"%@", newSourceString);
}
```

And I get the following log statements:

```
2010-04-17 23:50:13.913 CoreDataUISandbox[13417:a0f] -[RightViewController sourceDidChange:] { newSource = "Second View"; }
2010-04-17 23:50:13.914 CoreDataUISandbox[13417:a0f] -[RightViewController sourceDidChange:] (null)
2010-04-17 23:50:13.916 CoreDataUISandbox[13417:a0f] -[RightViewController sourceDidChange:] (null)
2010-04-17 23:50:13.917 CoreDataUISandbox[13417:a0f] -[RightViewController sourceDidChange:] (null)
2010-04-17 23:50:13.917 CoreDataUISandbox[13417:a0f] -[RightViewController sourceDidChange:] (null)
```

As you can see, the string is in the dictionary under the key `newSource`, yet when I call `objectForKey:`, I get `null`. I have even tried the fallback option of cleaning the project.

Has anyone ever run into this, or have I just forgotten something really basic?

Comment: Out of curiosity, after setting and logging `aDict`, what happens if you do `DLog(@"%@", [aDict allKeys]);`?

Comment: Is this the *actual* code? Any chance you mis-typed the key? What does `DLog(@"%@", [aDict allKeys])` give?

Comment: You might also want to try logging `newSourceString` with `%p` instead of `%@`.

Comment: I knew I had done something stupid that I couldn't find last night. Turns out I had aptered the version of DLog I found on iphoneincubator.com to not list the line number only I had only removed the __LINE__ part and not the [Line %d] part. Of course then I forgot that I had done that. I'm not sure why it only caused the NSStrings to have issues being logged and not the NSDictionary. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, you're left with a reporting error from DLog for some reason.

Try:

1. Logging with NSLog.
2. Check the value of `newSourceString` directly in the debugger while the code is live.

Answer (score 2):

> What would cause `objectForKey:` to return null with a valid string in place?

One of two things:

1. The dictionary does not contain an object for that key. (Whether you *think* it does is irrelevant.)
2. You don't have a dictionary; `aDict` is `nil`, so you're sending the `objectForKey:` message to `nil`. Messages to `nil` do nothing but return `nil`.

> As you can see the string is in the dictionary under the key newSource…

<del>Actually, I'm not sure what's going on there. An NSDictionary's description (if it contained a string for that key) would be `{ newSource = "some string here"; }`, which doesn't match the description you logged. On the other hand, if it were an object that isn't a dictionary, you should get a “does not respond to selector” exception upon trying to send it an `objectForKey:` message. So while it does appear, from your log output, to be *something*, I have no idea what it is, except that it is probably not a dictionary.</del>

That's just plain strange, then.

Comment: Every time I put in the curly braces they screwed up the code block so I had to delete them (still not sure why that was happening).

Comment: I've updated the question to include the curly braces in the log statement based on @theMikeSwan's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue.  For me the problem was that I thought my key was a NSString when it was actually a NSNumber.  You can check your key using the following

```
for (id key in [aDict allKeys]){
        NSLog(@"%@:%@",key, [[key class] description]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You fail to neglect the environment in which you're coding.  If it's with GNUstep, specifically, gnustep1.19, read on.  Otherwise ignore.

I just encountered a very odd bug with gnustep1.19(.3) but it mimics this question perfectly.

```
NSString * key = <some string>
NSDictionary * dict = <some dictionary>

(gdb) p [dict objectForKey:key]
$20 = (struct objc_object *) 0x0
(gdb) p [dict objectForKey:@"MyKeyValue"]
$22 = (struct objc_object *) 0x7fffd94fe690
(gdb) p [key compare"@MyKeyValue"]
$25 = NSOrderedSame
```

In this case, 'key' was being initialised by extracting it from another NSDictionary, and some of the entries in the other dictionary (loaded from a file) contain Unicode characters.  That is, so far, the only correlation I have found - removing the unicode from the source file and re-running the app makes it work.

This is not an issue for gnustep1.18 or >=gnustep1.20

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your string is actually, literally "(null)" -- that is to say, it is 6-letters long, and spells out (-n-u-l-l-).

Comment: The first line of the print out shows that the key does have a value of "Second View".

Comment: If that were the case, then the step that applies `stringByAppendingString:` should not still produce `(null)`.

Comment: No one thought this was really funny? I'm gonna play this as a prank on my partner some day =)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that aDict is not an instance of NSDictionary.
log it's class to confirm.